# Kubuntu: ugly widgets, weather app resets, plasma crashes

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, kde, widgets

Kubuntu 16.04, nvidia blob.

Widgets added to desktop look ugly: tiny in size by default, when enlarged, suddenly their headings (?) and icons have huge text size.

The weather widget and taskbar indicator resets back to Bonn-New York-etc, tried setting the location multiple times, no joy.

Creating new folder in Dolphin makes Plasma crash. Tried with both Intel and Nvidia driver (Optimus laptop). Also, there are two selections for 'Create folder' in Dolphin: one in English, and one in Russian, my l10n language. The latter doesn't make Plasma crash.

Where do I start digging to solve this problem?

Comment: As I guess you just installed the system. Then I'd rather recommend Kubuntu-based [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org/). Most Kubuntu problems are because Ubuntu releases made to accord Gnome releases, and once LTS released, packages are frozen with major versions, and often buggy KDE *(I can't just pull out the quotes, but that's what I gathered from many discussions on Phoronix, etc)*. KDE Neon is a Kubuntu supported by KDE foundation, with latest stable KDE. You can also just add their PPA, [but they warns it is nor tested neither supported](https://neon.kde.org/faq).